# Sql select statement always returns 4 records

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve a SQL query where i ALWAYS get 4 records, if one of the records does not exist it can be null.

Let's say i have the following table named names

```
Name id:       Name:
1              John
2              Mike
3              Marcel
```

Now i will use the following sql query:

```
Select names.name from names
```

I will get the following results

```
John
Mike
Marcel
```

But what i am trying to achieve is:

```
John
Mike
Marcel
NULL
```

so i always want 4 records even when there are only 3. Its not an option to add a 4th.

Someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, maybe this will help you going: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41067/getting-select-to-return-a-constant-value-even-if-zero-rows-match

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `union all` and `order by`.  You don't specify the database, but the following gives one method:

```
select name
from (select name
      from table t
      limit 4
     ) union all
     (select null union all
      select null union all
      select null union all
      select null
     )
order by (case when name is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
limit 4;
```

Some aspects of the syntax might vary, depending on the database, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with numbers (nr) as (
  values (1),(2),(3),(4)
)
select names.name
from numbers  
  left join (
      select id,
             name,
             row_number() over (order by id) as rn
      from names)
  ) names on names.rn = numbers.nr;
```

If you don't know if there are 3 or 4 rows in the table, you can apply a limit the join condition: `on names.rn = numbers.nr and names.nr <= 3`. This will ensure that you will never retrieve more than three rows from the `names` table.

If you you only care about the ids 1,2,3 and there will never be other IDs you can do something like this:

```
with numbers (nr) as (
  values (1),(2),(3),(4)
)
select names.name
from numbers  
  left join names on names.id = numbers.nr;
```

You can replace `4` with any value that will definitely not exist in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with simple SQL Query. Assuming that you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT TOP 4
   id,name
FROM
  (SELECT id, name from t
  UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 4
         NULL,null
     FROM sys.columns) T
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0c76/2)**